# uibutton animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, animation, uibutton

is there a possibility to animate an uibutton in this way that a thing or whatever comes out of the background e.g. a wheat ear comes out of a field.

is this possible?

thanks :)

Comment: So you want the wheat ear to be the button, and the field to be a background image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you want a more complicated animation, you can just create a custom type UIButton (either with IB by changing the type to Custom, or programmatically with `UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`), then set the button's image with `[aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheat_ear" forState:UIControlStateNormal]`.

To move it, just animate its position normally...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{aButton.center = newCenter;}];
```

Or, to provide the illusion of it coming out of the field, animate the bounds of the image so that it starts with the image's width and zero height, and ends with the image's width and height:

```
CGRect originalFrame = aButton.frame;
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x, originalFrame.origin.y, originalFrame.size.width, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{aButton.frame = originalFrame;}];
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example for the part you described lastly? (starts with the image's width and zero height, and ends with the image's width and height.)?

Comment: This was very helpful, but I got an error when I tried to use it as written. I needed to set origin and width:     aButton.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x, originalFrame.origin.y, originalFrame.size.width, 0);